# RXTX or owfs for Android App without root

Tags: android, android-ndk, serial-port, rxtx

i'm looking for a solution using RXTX or owfs for an Android App (Android 4.x) to communicate with a humidity sensor using USB host mode via USB to serial converter (DS9490B).

I must not use the /dev/ttyXXX socket, because android must stay on stock firmware without root access.

Compiling owfs for android (arm) as shared library failed, for x86_64 it works without errors.
Using Android NDK to compile owfs has thrown errors once more.

This project for RXTX on Android (http://www.v-lad.org/projects/gnu.io.android/) fails with the same infinite loop referenced here:
[RXTX serial port library on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377212/rxtx-serial-port-library-on-android)

Has anyone a working solution for this tragedy?

Thanks in advance!